# Can ActiveX, multi-select checkboxes hold values if I close/open the workbook?

Tags: excel, drop-down-menu, activex, multi-select

How do you have a dropdown, with multi-select, that holds its value after being saved and reopened? Here is what I already have setup and working:

- To, on click of a button object, have a drop-down list appear
- Each option in the list has a check-box, with the ability to select multiple boxes/list-items
- All of the selected list items appear in a list on a different tab for easy viewing

When I select a few list items, close the dropdown, save and close the Excel workbook, then reopen it, the drop-downs no longer show the items that I selected. The other tab, with easy viewing, does show the previously selected items. But when I go to the drop-downs and make another selection, it clears the easy viewing output and I've lost all the old data.

How do I make my ActiveX, multi-select drop down box hold its selections an open/close of the workbook does not lose the values? I am using a macro to show/hide the dropdown list on click of a button, but I don't think that is relevant. My problem is with the ActiveX box not holding values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save the value of DropDown in a cell. After when you open the workbook / show the DropDown, rebuilt the values.

```
Sub SaveL()
    Dim Str As String
    Str = ""
    For i = 0 To 9
        If ListBox1.Selected(i) = True Then
            Str = Str & "1"
        Else
            Str = Str & "0"
        End If
    Next
    Range("A1").Value = Str
End Sub

Sub OpenL()
    Dim Str As String
    Str = Range("A1").Value
    For i = 0 To 9
        If Mid(Str, i + 1, 1) = "1" Then
            ListBox1.Selected(i) = True
        Else
            ListBox1.Selected(i) = False
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

This macro save 1 or 0 if are selected or not in the cell A1.

Comment: Hi, again thanks, I have implemented and it works almost perfectly. The remaining problem is that I think the 0-9 is the number of options. Right now, when I save/open, any selection in the first 9 cells are saved, but selections on list items 15 or 20 items down are not retained. I have more than 9 list items and need to retain them all. But when I increase it to 25 in the VB code, then hit save, I get an error. How can I fix?

Comment: Still struggling. Is it possible that the problem is that output cell? I am looking at what gets output to cell A1 after I check list items that are 20 or 40 items down the list. I change the VB to the number of options, then try it out and it only retains about the first dozen list items. Scientific notation seems to be shortening the output. Just a thought. This is so close to working!

Comment: You need to set the cell like TEXT, otherwise it's taken like a number and don't work.

Comment: Thank you! I just realized I never replied but this was a huge help.